# Calculating Effective Address in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I need to calculate each line's effective address. I know you shift DS to the left once and add the offset but I am confused when you changing the default data segment? For the first line do I just add ES+DI instead of using DS?

Using these: [Register Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdYuY.png)
An example of one that I know is right

```
IN    AL, 70H

OUT  DX,  AX

OUT    21H ,  AL
```

Comment: ADD ES:[DI],AL -> address = (ES<<4) + DI

Comment: okay so the answer I got was 3A000H? Is there any way to type these into an emulator and check my answers?

Comment: Yes, by watching memory at address 03a000h and see if it is changed by that instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN/OUT do not use segment registers, the I/O address (port number) is specified either in an immediate operand

```
IN  AL, 70H    ; Read one byte from I/O port 70H
OUT 21H, AL    ; Write one byte to I/O port 21H
```

or in the DX register

```
OUT  DX,  AX   ; Write two bytes from AX to I/O port specified in DX
```

You gave the following values for registers

[image]

It is not obvious there which byte is the low byte and which is the high byte (x86 uses little-endian byte order).  Assuming DX has the value 0022H and AX is 2355H then

```
OUT  DX,  AX   ; Write 2355H (AX) to port 0022H (16-bit data bus)
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086

Comment: Okay so I got confirmation and everything is right but the OUT DX, AX. It does utilize both ports but the address bus only recognizes one which is port 0022H. Other than that it was an excellent answer!

Comment: Ahh, right, the 8086 had a 16-bit data bus.  I'll fix the answer.